# Duplicating index of pandas dataframe and adjusting age column randomly from 0.5-1 years

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code where I am duplicating each row in the original dataframe anywhere from 1-3 times. I want to update the age though with each duplication to be some random age between 0.5-1 years away but always increasing from the last age with the same id. How can I do this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)
d = {'ages': [11,94,30,64,57,19, np.NaN],
     'sex': [2,2,2,2,1,1,1]}
df = (
    pd
      .DataFrame(d)
      .dropna()
      .reset_index(drop = True)
      .assign(id_col = lambda x: x.index + 1)
      .loc[lambda x: x.index.repeat(np.random.uniform(1, 4, size = len(x)))] 
     )
```

Expected output might look something like this:

```
    ages    sex id_col
0   11.0    2   1
0   11.56   2   1
1   94.0    2   2
1   94.2    2   2
1   94.56   2   2
2   30.0    2   3
2   30.67   2   3
2   30.89   2   3
3   64.0    2   4
3   64.11   2   4
4   57.0    1   5
5   19.0    1   6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do what your question asks, starting with the code in OP and continuing with code that will update `ages` to have the desired characteristics:

```python
df.ages += ( df.groupby(level=0).ages.count().apply(lambda n: 
    [0] + sorted(np.random.uniform(0.5, 1.0, size=n-1))).explode() )
```

Output:

```
            ages  sex  id_col
index
0           11.0    2       1
0      11.529042    2       1
1           94.0    2       2
1      94.800558    2       2
1      94.933088    2       2
2           30.0    2       3
2      30.510292    2       3
2      30.854036    2       3
3           64.0    2       4
3      64.984955    2       4
4           57.0    1       5
5           19.0    1       6
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

Initial setup:

```
np.random.seed(42)
d = {'ages': [11,94,30,64,57,19, np.NaN],
     'sex': [2,2,2,2,1,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

#repeating the index
df=df.reindex(np.repeat(df.index,3))
```

so firstly filter out the duplicated index:

```
cond=df.index.duplicated()
```

Then use:
`np.random.uniform()` method and `np.round()` method and get some random age between 0.5-1 years

```
df.loc[cond,"ages"]+=sorted(np.round(np.random.uniform(0.5,1.0,size=cond.sum()),2))
df=df.assign(id_col=df.index+1).dropna(subset=["ages"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)
d = {'ages': [11,94,30,64,57,19, np.NaN],
     'sex': [2,2,2,2,1,1,1]}
df = (
    pd
      .DataFrame(d)
      .dropna()
      .reset_index(drop = True)
      .assign(id_col = lambda x: x.index + 1)
      .loc[lambda x: x.index.repeat(np.random.uniform(1, 4, size = len(x)))] 
     )

def update(g):
    g['ages'] = g['ages'] + ([0]+sorted([np.random.random() for i in range(len(g)-1)]))
    return g

df['ages'] = (df.groupby(df.index)
                .apply(lambda g: update(g) if len(g) > 1 else g)
                )

print(df)
```

```
        ages  sex  id_col
0  11.000000    2       1
0  11.352623    2       1
1  94.000000    2       2
1  94.108968    2       2
1  94.429704    2       2
2  30.000000    2       3
2  30.444279    2       3
2  30.906467    2       3
3  64.000000    2       4
3  64.619784    2       4
4  57.000000    1       5
5  19.000000    1       6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build another dataframe with some noise and concatenate with the original one. Since you're computing ages separately you don't need to use `groupby`:

```
def new_ages(df):
    # (1, 4) -> (0, 3) because you want to keep the original value
    repeat = np.random.randint(0, 3, len(df))
    noise = np.random.uniform(0.5, 1, repeat.sum())
    return (df.reindex(df.index.repeat(repeat))
              .assign(ages=lambda x: x['ages']+noise)
              .sort_values('ages'))

out = pd.concat([df, new_ages(df)]).sort_index()
print(out)

# Output
        ages  sex  id_col
0  11.000000    2       1
0  11.603971    2       1
0  11.712578    2       1
1  94.000000    2       2
1  94.515657    2       2
1  94.783850    2       2
2  30.000000    2       3
2  30.921142    2       3
3  64.000000    2       4
4  57.000000    1       5
4  57.724877    1       5
5  19.000000    1       6
5  19.697575    1       6
```

Input data

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(d).dropna().reset_index(drop = True)
        .assign(id_col = lambda x: x.index + 1))
print(df)

# Output
   ages  sex  id_col
0  11.0    2       1
1  94.0    2       2
2  30.0    2       3
3  64.0    2       4
4  57.0    1       5
5  19.0    1       6
```

Comment: I like this solution but I want to keep the input data the same as I specified in my question. For example I want the repeated noise part to be outside the function. Can you find a solution with this in mind?